# Showing login message when connecting to Screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen, remote, motd

I have added this to `.profile`:

```
[ -z "$STY" ] && screen -Rd "work"
```

When connecting to a remote machine via ssh, the automatic attachment to screen is hiding the server's motd (message of the day).

Can I tell Screen to show this message when first attaching, or at least insert a keypress block before hiding the motd?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it this way:

```
[ -z "$STY" ] && read && screen -Rd "work"
```

It will postpone the screen attaching after you will press enter (or input something). If you enter `Ctrl+D`, screen will not be attached and you will end up in normal shell.

Answer (score 0):

you can add into **~/.bashrc** line

```
cat /etc/motd
```

and after when you will go to the screen you will see welcome message